# CMake - Unable to link against ExternalProject

Tags: c++, cmake

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(BBPatchTool LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/aws/lib/cmake")

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core LinguistTools)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core LinguistTools)


set(TS_FILES BBPatchTool_en_US.ts)

include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(awscpp
        GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp.git
        GIT_TAG           1.11.178
        LIST_SEPARATOR    "|"
        CMAKE_ARGS       -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
        -DBUILD_ONLY=s3|logs
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/aws
        -DENABLE_TESTING=OFF
        BUILD_ALWAYS      TRUE
        TEST_COMMAND      ""
        BINARY_DIR        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/aws
)

add_executable(BBPatchTool
        main.cpp
        ${TS_FILES}
        BBProgressBar.cpp
        BBProgressBar.h
)
target_include_directories(BBPatchTool PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BBPatcher/)
target_include_directories(BBPatchTool PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/quazip)
target_include_directories(BBPatchTool PUBLIC "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/aws/include")

target_link_libraries(BBPatchTool Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Network BBPatcher HDiffPatch QuaZip aws-cpp-sdk-s3)

add_dependencies(BBPatchTool awscpp)

if(COMMAND qt_create_translation)
    qt_create_translation(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${TS_FILES})
else()
    qt5_create_translation(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${TS_FILES})
endif()

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS BBPatchTool
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)


if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
    target_compile_definitions(BBPatchTool PRIVATE DEVELOPMENT_ENV)
else()
    target_compile_definitions(BBPatchTool PRIVATE PRODUCTION_ENV)
endif()
```

The external project aws-cpp-sdk build no problem. However I am unable to link against it. I get this error:

```
[ 92%] Completed 'awscpp'
[ 96%] Built target awscpp
[100%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target BBPatchTool
[100%] Built target BBPatchTool_autogen
[100%] Linking CXX executable BBPatchTool
ld: library not found for -laws-cpp-sdk-s3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [BBPatchTool/BBPatchTool] Error 1
make[2]: *** [BBPatchTool/CMakeFiles/BBPatchTool.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [BBPatchTool/CMakeFiles/BBPatchTool.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [BBPatchTool] Error 2
```

Any idea why I get this error and how can I fix it so that I can link towards this ExternalProject ?

Comment: Should it be `aws-cpp-sdk-core`?

Comment: @273K same issue.

Comment: It can't be the same, the error must be changed and not tell about `aws-cpp-sdk-s3`.

Comment: You need to specify **absolute path** to the library (libraries) in the awscpp project which you want to link with.